# When to create facebook hosted objects using Object API instead of self hosted objects, for use with Open Graph API to publish Stories?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I could use any of these two solutions: self hosted objects using meta tags in HTMLs OR the facebook hosted solution using Object API. But what is the advantage or disadvantage of each or how do I decide what to use for my case ?

I need to publish stories of user activities on my app to facebook using custom app specific objects & actions.

Comment: I am having problem in implementation of self hosted object in android. Please check my question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995978/how-to-use-self-hosted-objects-to-create-custom-stories-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995978/how-to-use-self-hosted-objects-to-create-custom-stories-in-android) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966283/facebook-custom-story-share-using-javascript-sdk-showing-erroraction-requires?sfb=2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966283/facebook-custom-story-share-using-javascript-sdk-showing-erroraction-requires?sfb=2)

Comment: if you can help me please let me know, Do u have any valuable link  regarding the same it will be helpful for me . Thanks

Comment: @user01 can you say please how you solve your problem? What type (self-hosted or facebook-hosted using Object API) did you choose?  what is the advantage or disadvantage of each?