# Facebook custom story share using JavaScript sdk() showing error(Action Requires At Least One Reference)

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-stream-story, custom-stories

I am using JavaScript sdk for one of my Facebook canvas game application. I am trying to implement custom story share dialog to post story on user wall.

The information available on developer site is unclear and limited.The bellow code is for sharing custom story using open grap API. Bellow code is available on Facebook developer site link provided(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog). The Facebook provided code is working fine as its using predefined action_type.

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'share_open_graph',
   action_type: 'og.likes',
   action_properties: JSON.stringify({
   object:'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
    })
  }, function(response){});
```

I have create an object(cricket) and action(play) for custom story on FB Developer console  App's Open Graph tab.i have created a self hosted Object(html page) called cricket.html.Bellow is the content or my html page.i verified the html page on Open Graph Object Debugger.Graph Object Debugger showing me all the information, what i have given with no errors or warnings .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta property="fb:app_id"          content="*************" /> 
<meta property="og:type"            content="appnamespace:cricket" /> 
<meta property="og:title"           content="App for u" /> 
<meta property="og:url"               content="https://example.com/appnamespace/cricket.html" /> 
<meta property="og:description"     content="Find me on facebook for u" /> 
<meta property="og:image"           content="https://example.com/appnamespace/image/any_time_share.png" /> 

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Bellow is my code where I am replacing:- 
og.likes ---to--->appnamespace:play("play"is my action).

Is i am doing any thing wrong here ? please let me know.

```
function customshare()
{
FB.ui({
method: 'share_open_graph',
action_type: 'appnamespace:play',
action_properties: JSON.stringify(
{
  object:'https://example.com/appnamespace/cricket.html',
})
},
 function(response){});
 }
```

However i am getting the below error while executing the FB.ui method: 'share_open_graph' for custom share.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got my problem solved by simple changing this:-

```
object:'https://example.com/appnamespace/cricket.html',
```

To

```
cricket:'https://example.com/appnamespace/cricket.html',
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention the url in url field of object i guess then only it will work and cricket field is missing as seen from your error message

Comment: Please mention where I give the URL field in html or javascript